# How to find the next greater available record in SQL if the one that I entered is not found

Tags: c#, sql, linq

mytable is the next

```
Part Number     Voltage Amp HP
MMX34AA014F0-0      480 14  10
MMX34AA016F0-0      480 16  10
DC1-34018FB-A20N    480 18  10
```

I want to search a record in my Db for example HP = '10' And [Amp ]= '14'
It should give me MMX34AA014F0-0 this and that’s Ok

But if HP = '10' And [Amp ]= '13' it should give me MMX34AA014F0-0 this

```
Part Number     Voltage [Amp]   HP
MMX34AA014F0-0  480 14  10
```

And if HP = '10' And [Amp ]=  '15' it should give me MMX34AA016F0-0 this

```
Part Number     Voltage  [Amp]  HP
MMX34AA016F0-0  480 16  10
```

How can I do this?
Because in the way that I am doing it is retrieving all the records greater than Amp that I enter and what I really want is if the value that I enter in [amp] variable is not found search for the next value that is greater than the one I entered

Comment: do you want linq or sql?

Comment: SELECT [Part Number]      
      ,[Amp]   
  FROM mytable 
  Where  [Voltage] = '480'  And [HP] = '10' And ([Amp] = '14' OR [Amp] = '16' Or [Amp] = '18' ) if amp=14 is not found it should continue and search for the next  and so on and if the value is found it stops and this is a huge table with a bunch of differents values.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you what you want where @hp is your `hp` variable and @amp is your `amp` variable.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE [HP] = @hp
   AND [AMP] = (SELECT MIN([AMP]) FROM mytable WHERE [HP] = @hp AND [AMP] >= @amp)
```

Answer (score 1):

In microsoft t-sql, I've done something like this:

```
select top 1 * from table t1 where t1.value >= 10 order by value
```

(This would return 10 if it were there, but give me 11, 12, 13, etc if 10 were not in the table.)

I think you could do something similar with the "limit" command in mySQL since "top" is a MS t-sql command.

Comment: need to order by `value` to be sure.